# how to change color of the text based on background color on run time css

Tags: css

I have

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dynamicColor}">ABC</span>
```

I want to set the font color of text based on the background color that is inverted color of `background-color` so that is easily readable. Like if `background-color` is white then text color should be black. And if `background-color` is black then text color is white.

In sass, I could do this easily using the following function

```
// function to return the text-color based on the passed background color
@function text-color($color) {
    @if (lightness($color) > 50) {
        @return #000000; // Lighter backgorund, return dark color
    }
    @else {
        @return #ffffff; // Darker background, return light color
    }
}
```

but the `background-color` is getting changed run time based on the dynamic content using **AJAX**.

**Update**

Added more detail to clear the question.

Comment: Can you please explain how is it duplicate?

Comment: You can make use of `color: dynamicTextColor` inside `[ngStyle]`.

Comment: Is your question how to add color to ngStyle or how to invert dynamicColor?

Comment: @SunilGarg Seems like you want to achieve the same here (binding a color to ngStyle). I would recommend to check the answers in that question. If it does not answer your question than it's not a duplicate, but I have the strong feeling it does. (But then you probably may want to change the title of your question)

Comment: I think angular tag should be added to help users know that angular solution is needed not just css, in case only angular solution is needed :/

Comment: Question has been updated I need inverted color of text based on the background color

Comment: can you explain how the background color is getting changed ?

Comment: Dynamic data using ajax

Answer (score 0):

When ngStyle change, color while change!

element:

```
<span ngStyle="{\"backgroundColor\":\"#000\"}">ABC</span>
```

js:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var dom = document.querySelector("[ngStyle]");
    var temp = JSON.parse(dom.getAttribute("ngStyle"));
    dom.style.color = (temp.backgroundColor === "#000" ? "#fff" : "#000")
}, 16)
```

Comment: there could be any color . i just given black/white as an example